# need advice in making login app which redirects user to change password page for first time login

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

i need your advice on this

i'm making login application,it has to check if the user is logging in for the first time and redirect to change password page if the user is logging in for the first time.my approach is i'm 
adding one extra column by the name "last_login" in a table that i need to validate with during the login.The logic that i want to implement is, during the registration  i will update that column to null and i will check every time a user tries to login if the  "last_login" field is empty and if it is empty it means that he or she is logging in for the first time so i will redirect him to change password page and once after changing the password i will update the field with current time.

so,my question is this good way to deal with this problem if not can someone please help me with this.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to make something more flexible - create a column like "reset_required" bit (1 or 0). When a new user is created and a random password is generated set it to 1. When they request a password reset and they get a temporary password set it to 1. When you have some kind of security issue and you need people to reset passwords, set it to 1. Otherwise though, I think your solution would work fine

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the best solution for the problem.